# How to restart docker container without log level?

Tags: docker

I have a running container with log level set to JSON. I want to restart the container with log level set to `none`.

I tried using `docker restart --log-driver none <CONTAINER_ID>`, but it didn't work.

How can I restart my docker container with out log levels?

Comment: I don't see any `--log-level` flag for `docker run`. Can you give some more information about how you originally started the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize it was referring to `--log-driver`. If this is the case and you absolutely can't remove the container and start a new one, there is an option. You can manually edit the `hostconfig.json` file to change the logging driver and restart the Docker daemon.

Example:

I start a container that logs the date output every 10 seconds:

```
$ docker run -d --log-driver json-file --name mytest alpine sh -c "while true; do echo \$(date); sleep 10; done"
edf6bb60088ded11d991b6f31bc7091e2f6b81552937471beeafc5f271697a6f
$ docker logs mytest              
Mon Apr 3 21:27:08 UTC 2017
Mon Apr 3 21:27:18 UTC 2017
Mon Apr 3 21:27:28 UTC 2017
```

Now I stop the container:

```
$ docker stop mytest
```

Edit the `hostconfig.json` file (first SSH to my Docker machine):

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
docker@default:~$ sudo vi /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/776d9c6d63c5e229fe4ce4bfe534f42cc9d1f04df7699171ce28414c4f086a63/hostconfig.json
```

Find `"Type":"json-file"` and change to `"Type":"none"` and save.

Now restart the Docker daemon (and exit SSH):

```
docker@default:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart
docker@default:~$ exit
```

Start your container again:

```
$ docker start mytest
```

No more logs:

```
$ docker  logs mytest
"logs" command is supported only for "json-file" and "journald" logging drivers (got: none)
```

Answer (score 0):

`log-level` is a deprecated command, I think you mean `--log-driver`

You can't set the log level during restart or using `docker update` either, so the only way is to kill the container and start again. Hopefully you used a volume for your persistent data.

```
docker kill <id>
docker run --log-driver=none
```